# How would I write this if statement

Tags: if-statement

The condition is that a product gets a discount if it is bought on september 15th through october 15th. How would I write an if statement for this?

You could start off with:

`if ((month != 9 || month != 10) && (day....`

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

```
if (month == 9 && day >= 15) || (month == 10 && day <=15)
```

Answer (score 0):

`if((month == 9 && day >= 15) || (month == 10 && day <= 15)) { }`

Answer (score -1):

```
if ((month == 9 && day >= 15) || (month == 10 && day <= 15))
```

Comment: this would be incorrect, this statement can never be true except if the day is 15

Comment: my answer is the correct one because it has an and condition between the two

Comment: If for example month was 9 and day was 19: ```(month >= 9 && day >= 15)``` would be true but ```(month <= 10 && day <= 15)``` would be false. An and operator would return false, please check your code

Comment: you're right @ÖzgürGüzeldereli